# Mix 2 videos with FFmpeg (overlay one on top of other)

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, mp4, effect

I using `ffmpeg` through `Android-NDK`. I've 2 pieces of the videos , The first one is my main video and the second one is my effect video.

Now I wanna mix this 2 videos together, Is it possible ?

Note : Both videos decoding through MP4 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to translate this into the API offhand, but the command-line version of what you're trying to do is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -vf 'movie=effect.mp4 [f];[in][f] overlay=0:0 [out]' out.mp4
```

See the [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) on [movie](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#movie) and [overlay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay-1) for more information.

Comment: Hi blahdiblah, Finally I find a way that we can run ffmpeg commands through execute on android, but I confuse on the word that in the beginning of the command line, I mean "ffmeg ..." in Android it should be "/data/package/ffmpeg" What should I put in ffmpeg folder, the original ffmpeg or something else?

Comment: Can't help you I'm afraid, I don't know where it usually gets installed.

Comment: Okay , I tried to use this command on windows but I got an error from "-vf" word.

Comment: Maybe you're using an old version of ffmpeg?  Video filters have been around for a while now.

Comment: Yes, I use an old version of ffmpeg and test it in the new version and it worked. Is it possible to write this command line to c code?

Comment: Probably, but unfortunately I haven't worked much with the API so I can't.

Comment: Okay, Where can I find the API that I need to write this command line in c code?

Comment: The link to the docs that I included in the answer is an excellent starting point.